# How do I change my sender name when using sendmail (not email address, but the name displayed)

Tags: linux, sendmail

I am using Red Hat Linux Server. When using sendmail to send emails, how do I change the name that appears in email clients.

Right now I just see the email address. user@domain.com. I would like  Firstname Lastname displayed. How do I configure this?

I tried specifying `--from "Firstname Lastname <user@domain.com>"`, but what I ended up seeing in my email client when receiving mail was literally:

"Firstname Lastname `<user@domain.com>"@domain.com`

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked the man page for sendmail?  I found this: "-Ffullname  Set the full name of the sender."

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change username of the sender using /etc/passwd or using `usermod` command ?

try it